# ASP.NET IsNewSession not working with incognito Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, browser

I'm trying to check if a session is new, and if it is, do something.

To check if a session is new I'm using

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession) 
{
    // Log "is new session"         
}
else 
{
    // Log "is NOT new session"
}
```

To test this I open a new incognito Chrome window and browse to my site. The first time after building it logs "is new session". I then close Chrome and open another incognito window but this time I get "is NOT new session" and the same for subsequent tries.

I've looked at the cookie ASP.NET_SessionId and it's different each time.

Doesn't that mean it is then a new session? Does ASP.NET use anything else to check for a new session?

Update:

I've done more tests and this appears to only be a problem in incognito Chrome and Firefox. When using Chrome and Firefox in normal mode, the IsNewSession property returns true when the browser is closed and opened again.

Comment: As a work around I'm not using the IsNewSession property. I'm checking for a cookie "NewSession", if it doesn't exist I add a session cookie "NewSession". For subsequent requests in that session that cookie will exist, for new sessions it won't.